# Ошибка запуска Qt приложения

Tags: mingw, qt

Здравствуйте.
На днях начал изучать Qt по 2-м книгам, скачал себе QtSDK сначала, с ним же и QtCreator поставился.
Затем скачал версию Qt с открытым исходным кодом и MinGW, настроенным для работы с Qt. Написал простенькое Qt-приложение, ну просто консольное. Выполнил все инструкции, как в книге и говорилось:

```
qmake -project
qmake qt-tmp.pro
make
```

Всё собралось как нужно, но приложение не запустилось, падает с ошибкой:

"Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll. Попробуйте переустановить программу. "

Почему? Я гуглил по этой проблеме, там одна ссылка дельная была, но там парень переносил свой проект на другой компьютер, из-за чего оно и не работало, но у меня то на этом компьютере даже не запускается и почему-то в книге о том, что такая ошибка могла вылететь и речи нет. Я читал, что возможно это из-за того, что нужно отредактировать один файл и там сделать ещё пару настроек и тогда оно всё будет юзать статическую линковку. Но ведь это как-то не очень круто, если все приложения, которые я буду писать, придется статически линковать? Почему это происходит и какими методами можно это решить? Ладно бы писало, что не хватает Q*.dll файлов, можно было бы понять и скинуть в папку с приложением к примеру, но оно тащит какие-то gccшные библиотеки, т.е. как-то к MinGW привязано что ли, почему?

Тем более, что если создавать и запускать приложения через QtCreator, то проблем не возникает.

Кто-то, должно быть, пользовался же Qt, если да, то помогите пожалуйста объяснить почему так и помочь решить проблему.

Answer (score 5):

Просто добавьте папку с этой dll-кой в PATH — подозреваю, что она идет с MinGW — или же просто скопируйте ее в папку с вашей программой. Первый вариант лучьше, т.к. libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll может оказаться не единственной нужной вашей программе для запуска, но если будете переносить на другой комп, то придется все же копировать.

Comment: Не могу ответить у себя в ветке, отвечу здесь, требование длл от компилятора ИМХО более логично чем делать костыли, которые бы перобразовывали поведение компиляторов друг в друга, тем более что используется всего 3 варианта, два из которых частенько ставятся с чем-нибудь еще.

Comment: @aknew что-то я ничего не понял.

Comment: Добавил в PATH путь к dllке, ну т.е. с SDK там была папка mingw, в ней bin, этот путь и добавил.
Попробовал запустить - уже другая ошибка: "Точка входа в процедуру _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE не найдена в библиотеке DLL libstdc++-6.dll.", dllка эта есть в bin, т.е. насколько я понимаю, то уже к какой-то функции в dll не может получить доступ программа, вернее этой функции там нету что ли?

Answer (score 2):

Приложение при запуске run из QtCreator запускается в немного другой среде т.к. криейтор знает местоположение нужных библиотек, вот там все и хорошо. Чтобы приложение нашло библиотеку, она должна лежать либо в папке с ним, либо в system32 (?, уже не помню как в винде, а с 64 бит я вообще кажется не работал), либо прописывать относительные или абсолютные пути где-то в приложении (как вариант, в настройках), либо еще с path можно поиграть (?)
Так что смело используйте указанную ссылку.

Comment: Спасибо. Использовать ссылку, в смысле изменить опции qmake, чтобы он делал статическую линковку? Я-то не против... Но просто... Неужели все приложения мне теперь статически линковать? Т.е. допустим если я в том же QtCreator напишу приложение, скомплиирую, то в ВУЗе оно на компьютере не запустится?

Comment: в том и смысл длл - не тащить для каждой проги на qt библиотеку, а только один экземпляр для всех приложений (ну еще немного нагрузка на комп при исполнении одновременно многих программ снижается за счет того что вызывается эта длл  только один раз), так что для запуска где угодно либо статическая линковка, либо покидайте все длл в папку с программой

Comment: Я понимаю, но именно в данном случае у меня не запускается из-за libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll - это ведь не Qt-шная библиотека, больше похоже на юниксовую какую-то, у меня в Arch Linux библиотеки именно такой формат названий имеют. Т.е. полагаю, что это MinGWшная какая-то, которую тоже использовало при компиляции libGCC таки же...

Comment: Не уверен что это возможно, вообще-то почти все компиляторы таскают за собой доп длл для более-менее сложных приложений, тот же компилятор Visual C++ их хранит в Visual Studio Redistributable 200х (или что-то вроде того) в Program Files и прекрасно себя чувствует

Comment: Кстати, эта длл скорее всего зависимость кьюта, я тут вспомнил как как-то раз набросал консольную программку с opencv, из C++ там были только cout и string и никаких длл от minGW не потребовлось, только от opencv. Так что @dword прав, эта длл только начало, дальше будут еще

Comment: @aknew нет, это библиотека *gcc*, *MinGW* — его порт под винду, к Qt она не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Я знаю, но это не мешает Qt опираться какой-то частью на библиотеку компилятора

Comment: @aknew мешает то, что виндовая версия Qt собирается в Visual Studio — родным компилятором для этой операционки. MinGW используют далеко не все. Представьте, у человека есть проект, сделанный в студии, а Qt разработчики, предположим, собрали в MinGW, тогда этому человеку в обязательном порядке нужны будут gcc библиотеки помимо Redistributable. Так что виндовой Qt не нужна libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll.

Comment: В составе последнего (версия 1.2.1) QtSDK для windows идёт 3 варианта скомпилированных библиотек: для vs2008, vs2010 и MinGW. Та что скомпилирована MinGW требует наличия некоторых ddl-ок из каталога bin компилятора MinGW который идёт в составе SDK.

Только что собрал приложение с помощю MinGW из SDK 1.2.1. Запустил в чистой win xp под виртуалкой. Для запуска кроме QtCore.dll и QtGui.dll необходимы mingwm10.dll и libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll. Где их брать я написал выше.

Comment: @mks по мне так это странно и нелогично, ну раз вы говорите, и уверены в своих словах… — причин вам не верить у меня нет.

Comment: Только что собрал приложение с помощю MinGW из SDK 1.2.1. Запустил в чистой win xp под виртуалкой. Для запуска кроме QtCore.dll и QtGui.dll необходимы mingwm10.dll и libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll. Где их брать я написал выше.

Comment: Спасибо за ваши такие обсуждения - они тоже немного добавили понимания того как оно по-логике работает (вся эта линковка и т.п.). Ну а если мне нужно будет перенести приложение на другой ПК, то мне 2 варианта:статически линковать и тогда ничего с собой не брать, либо динамически и ложить в папку с программой.

1. А если я хочу какие-то библиотеки слинковать статически, а какие-то динамические, то можно ли как-то это сделать? Как в QtCreator и в MinGW? 

2. В случае дин.линковки если я положу библиотеки в папку %current_dir%/dlls - оно будет работать?(или path придется модифицировать всё равно